# Wordpress navigation menu color, changes for each chosen page

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and i'm trying to have my navigation display a color for that active navigation link IE a blue link on home when home page selected and a red link on services page when services page clicked.

I'm trying to do this using CSS. The navigation code is below:

```
<div id="menu-secondary" class="site-navigation menu-container" role="navigation">
<span class="menu-toggle">Menu</span>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="menu">
<ul id="menu-secondary-items" class="nav-menu sf-js-enabled">
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21">
<a href="http://whenthecatsaway.co.nz/">Home</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20">
<a href="http://whenthecatsaway.co.nz/?page_id=6">Welcome</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19">
<a href="http://whenthecatsaway.co.nz/?page_id=8">Services</a>
</li>
```

Here is CSS that makes each current active link be yellow.

```
#menu-secondary li.current-menu-item a {
  color: #FFCC33;
}
```

but i want each page to show a different color.

I'm thinking of something like this,  but its not working

```
#menu-secondary li. menu-item-18{
    color: #0F0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I can tell you that "li." doesn't make much sense. A period *before* a name means a class selector, but I don't think it has any meaning afterwards. Try getting rid of the space and see where you are.

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't seem to work.  

  How would you go about doing this

  -Click on services page in navigation.
  -When services page active, display red.
  -When Home page selected, display blue (this action turns services color off)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read too closely last time. You'll need to reference the ID of the menu item with a #. e.g. #menu-item-19 a{color: #0F0;}

Comment: #menu-item-19 a{color: #0F0;} It worked Jere but I want it to only show the color when the services page is selected all other times it remains the normal color.

Comment: I'll give it one more shot: "#menu-item-19.current-menu-item a{color: #0F0;}"

Comment: Thanks Jere that did exactly what i wanted. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Jere I also want an images to display in my sidebar only when the page is selected (Like you have done for the colors) 

Could I use the code you said there to do this?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how to do that, mainly because I wouldn't know all the various classes/IDs in wordpress. Maybe ask a new question? I would also suggest learning about [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)  and learning a good developer tool (chrome developer tools are amazing and not at all hard) so you can inspect the various classes/IDs easily.

Comment: I'm stuck on this problem right now. Would I put `"#menu-item-19.current-menu-item a{color: #0F0;}"` in my child theme style.css when using genesis? Thank-you!

Comment: @mattnewbie Yes, that should work. See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/current-menu-item-functionality-to-make-hover-state-and-active-state-the-same.      #header ul.menu li.current-menu-item a {
color: #F9B233;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target a div with an ID and Class active at the same time like so:

```
#menu-secondary #menu-item-18.current-menu-item a{
    color: #0F0;
}
```

As a sidenote, avoid using the li at the start when using an ID , like:

```
li.#menu-item-18.current-menu-item
```

as you're just slowing things down (an ID is already unique so doesn't need the li specified).